# Error when trying to view profile list on frontend by public

Tags: profile, joomla

I suspect this issue is one of a single configuration not being set properly, but I am at my wit's end to figure out which one...

I am trying to create a public directory of a CiviCRM group of contacts.

I have set up a profile and indicated it to be used for form & list as well as search. Each field of this profile is set to "Public User Pages and Listings" and visible.

In the CiviCRM configuration in the backend of Joomla, I gave permission to public users to view all contacts, view their (my) contacts, profile view, access all custom data.

I created a Joomla Menu defined as public and of the CiviCRM profile list type (associated to the correct profile).

When I try to open the menu, I get an error stating that the "the contact ID parameter to see the contact registration with a profile was not found" (free translation as it is written in French in my DB)

[image]

A registered user, on the other hand) can see the directory, so it has to do with a public user not having a contact ID...

What am I missing? How can I have the system overcome this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Related question** (I assume), when a registered user goes to this page, the first thing he sees is his own profile and need to click the "Return to contact list" to view all contacts. Is there a way to make this directory direct so the user sees the table right away?

**Follow-up after June 15th comments**: 
Registered as a test school and when to the URL:
[image]

Clicked "Return to contact list" and copied the URL for that list:
https://voile.qc.ca/fr/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=1046&force=1&gid=14

Closed session and copied list link public site. Arrived directly at the list w/o the registered user profile data. 
[image]

It thus seems that the option to view the contact profile needs to be turned off somehow.

But how?

Thanks!

Comment: it may help people help if you post (anonymised) urls of what people are going to

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. I did not think it would be of any use, being in another language, but here it goes. I added the screenshot in the original question. This is what a non registered person sees when trying to reach the "public" directory.

Comment: Thx but i was asking about the url people are on when they get this

Comment: ie you say "when a registered user goes to this page, the first thing he sees is his own profile" so what url are they visiting when they see this

Comment: Ah sorry.  Misunderstood. This is the URL: https://www.voile.qc.ca/fr/formation/trouver-un-club-ecole-ou-camp-membre/selon-services-offerts   Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: ah right. i don't know anything about joomla so I was expecting a pure civicrm path. is the above just how joomla does things or are you using some form of alias? Can you copy the civicrm path that you should find when looking at the Profile in the admin screens

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for you trying to help. Your request got me thinking and I tried the above-mentioned test (added to the original question). It ssems that I need to find a way to tell CiviCRM not to show the logged in user's profile, but to go directly to the list. - as public does not have a profile! Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: have you set your profile to be used for a 'search'?

Comment: Yes I have. As well as list profile. :/

Answer (score 1):

Finally what I did is create a URL type menu (instead of a CiviCRM profile view menu) with the URL of the list once the "return to list" link is clicked. This way, a user does not need to be logged in to see the list.